# Subclasses or characterizations of modular or pseudo-modular planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, metric-spaces

We say that a graph G is modular if for every three vertices x,y,z there exists a vertex w that lies on a shortest path between every two of x, y, z. Pseudo-modular (or "3-Helly") graphs are defined in the following link: http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_203.html.

I am wondering if there are interesting examples of planar graphs which are modular or pseudo-modular, or an interesting characterization of planar graphs which have these properties.

Answer (score 2):

The [median graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_graph) are a subclass of modular graphs with almost the same definition but where the vertex w is always unique. The [squaregraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaregraph) (plane graphs in which all bounded faces are quadrilaterals and all vertices either have degree 4 or belong to the unbounded face) form a natural and interesting subclass of the planar median graphs. I believe that all planar median graphs can be constructed by gluing together cubes and squaregraphs, but I don't think this result has been published.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am hoping for a more general classification or subclass of planar modular or pseudomodular graphs; the existence of a unique median, in particular, is a little too strong of a condition

Comment: I posted another partial answer (the graphs of 2d modular lattices) on my blog at http://11011110.livejournal.com/334654.html — but I think this still is far from a more general classification.